# Searching dropdown contents for string

Tags: webdriver, c#

I have a simple solution to search for a string within a dropdown menu, but I would like to improve the code so it allows more options, preferable storing each option as a separate entry in a list or array which I can iterate through

I get the contents using this method and assert the string exists:

```
var dropdown = Driver.FindElement(element);
var dropdownText = dropdown.Text;
Assert.IsTrue(dropdownText.Contains("teststring"));
```

This method works, however the problem I have is that dropdown.text is just one long string, with each element separated by "\r\n".  I have tried to store them in an IList using:

```
IList<string> elementTexts =  Driver.FindElements(element).Select(a => a.Text).ToList();
```

But this gave the same results as my current method (one long string stored in a single entry in the list).

Is there a better way to perform this search or store the dropdown strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want every dropdown value in a List, try using this:

```
    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("selection"));
    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
          // actions on every option, like extracting the value
    }
```

Alternatively, convert your WebElement `el` to a SelectElement:

```
SelectElement dropdown = new SelectElement(el);
```

The `dropdown.Options` attribute will get you the same list as above.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer I accepted above, I'm now using the following code when I need to do this:

```
var dropdown = Driver.FindElement(element);
var optionList = new List<string>();
optionList = dropdown.Text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

Now I can search within the list for a string to see if it is present in the dropdown.